# How do I implement my eCommerce host's API?

Tags: xml, api, e-commerce, implementation

I'm trying to generate a product page using my stores API but not sure how to begin.

Here is the product page now http://www.imagedepotinc.com/Image_Depot_Store/Products. If I had access to the code, I would just tweak it until it was set up how I wanted. Since I don't have access though, the only option they have for me is to build it from the ground up.

My eCommerce host is inksoft and they do not provide the most helpful technical support or have any documentation. All I have been told is "here are the API files, but we don't know what they do".

The "API" files they gave me are a list of some links such as the one below:

> http://www.imagedepotinc.com/GetProductCategoryList/2585

and when you click on one, it takes you to an XML file(are the XML files the API?):

```
<ProductCategoryList>
<vw_product_categories product_category_id="45904" name="Printed Apparel" path="Printed Apparel" thumburl_front="REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/892/ProductCategories/Printed_Apparel/80.gif"/>
<vw_product_categories product_category_id="8920007" parent_id="45904" name="T-Shirts" path="Printed Apparel -> T-Shirts" thumburl_front="REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/892/ProductCategories/Printed_Apparel/T-Shirts/80.gif"/>
<vw_product_categories product_category_id="45907" name="Promotional Items" path="Promotional Items" thumburl_front="REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/892/ProductCategories/Promotional_Items/80.gif"/>
<vw_product_categories product_category_id="45906" name="Digital Printed Products" path="Digital Printed Products" thumburl_front="REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/892/ProductCategories/Digital_Printed_Products/80.gif"/>
<vw_product_categories product_category_id="45939" parent_id="45906" name="Banners" path="Digital Printed Products -> Banners" thumburl_front="REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/892/ProductCategories/Digital_Printed_Products/Banners/80.gif"/>
</ProductCategoryList>
```

I've been searching for information on how to implement my store's API, but I can't find anything helpful.

Thanks in advanced, and sorry if I'm vague.

Answer (score 0):

you can create solid APIs either with zend-frameworks or epiphany

Comment: Thanks. This may be a little over my head but I will do some research.